# Changed permissions of docker volumes folder > You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: permissions, docker, rsync, nextcloud

I am running an instance of nextcloudpi in docker. I wanted to sync the data folder between two server via rsync, but got a permission folder. So I tried to give my user "John" the permission to read the folder. It seems I did something wrong as know the instance cannot access the data folder and in the browser when trying to access nextcloud, I get "You don't have permission to access this resource."
Can someone please tell me how to fix this? What should the permissions in the folder are? Right know, I have the following permissions:

```
$:/var/lib/docker$ sudo ls -l
drwx--x--x 4 root root 8 Mai 28 20:09 buildkit
drwx------ 3 root root 3 Jun 17 18:25 containers
drwx------ 3 root root 3 Mai 28 20:09 image
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 3 Mai 28 20:09 network
drwx------ 4 root root 4 Mai 28 20:09 plugins
drwx------ 2 root root 2 Jul  2 17:14 runtimes
drwx------ 2 root root 2 Mai 28 20:09 swarm
drwx------ 2 root root 2 Jul  2 17:14 tmp
drwx------ 2 root root 2 Mai 28 20:09 trust
drwxr--r-- 3 root root 5 Jul  2 17:14 volumes
drwx------ 3 root root 3 Mai 28 20:10 zfs

$ sudo ls -l volumes
total 7
brw------- 1 root root 0, 64 Jul  2 17:14 backingFsBlockDev
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 32768 Jul  2 17:14 metadata.db
drwxr--r-- 3 root root     3 Mai 28 20:11 ncdata
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid permission issues, I would recommend using [linuxserver.io's NextCloud image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/nextcloud). Here you can set the PGID and PUID easily in the docker or docker-compose configuration file.

For instance, if the PGID and PUID of `John` is 1000, just use the default value.

Generally, for the data for each container, you should have the following permissions:

- For files: `-rw-r--r--  1 John`
- And for directories: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 John`

Also, did you add the user `John` to the `docker` group? Use this command:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker John
```

Confirm with the `groups` command, that you're a member of the `docker` group.

Comment: I added John to the group and set all the permissions to -rwxr-xr-x. But I still have a permission error. What happens if I reinstall docker completely (sudo apt reinstall docker-compose)? Will this fix the permission and keep the volumes? Or are the volume deleted then?

Comment: You should try and remake the NextCloud container with the proper permissions. Also note, that `docker-compose` is not `docker`. `docker-compose` is "only" an abstraction layer that allows you to configure containers with `.yaml` files instead of command parameters.

Comment: Also, I don't believe persistent volumes are deleted, unless you specify this.